# Check type in Xtend validator

Tags: java, validation, xtext, xtend

I want to check the type of an feature inside my Xtend validator.

The Xtext grammar looks like the following:

```
Element:
    'Element' name=ID
    'feature' feature=DOUBLE
    'end' 'Element'
;
```

This is how it is used:

```
Element MyElement
    feature 2.5
end Element
```

If trying to use a `INTEGER` value instead of `DOUBLE` for `feature`, the editor shows the error:

> mismatched input '84900' expecting RULE_DOUBLE

I would like to overwrite the message. Therefore I've created a validation method inside my validator. In the method I would like to check the type of the feature. This is what I am trying to do:

```
@Check
def checkFeatureType(Element element) {
    if (element.feature instanceof Double) {
        // shows error!
    }
}
```

The `instanceof` check shows the following error:

> Incompatible conditional operand types double or Double and Double
>      or double

How can I perform a type check or is there a better way to override the standard message mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastian, I've found the solution.

First of all, it is necessary to add an `SyntaxErrorMessageProvider` to the `RuntimeModule`, which has the name `<LanguageName>RuntimeModule`. In case of the given example in my opening post, it would be `MyLanguageRuntimeModule`.

```
public class MyLanguageRuntimeModule extends my.language.AbstractMyLanguageRuntimeModule {
    public Class<? extends org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGenerator> bindIGenerator() {
        return my.language.generator.MyLanguageGenerator.class;
    }

    public Class<? extends ISyntaxErrorMessageProvider> bindISyntaxErrorMessageProvider() {
        return MyLanguageSyntaxErrorMessageProvider.class;
    }
}
```

After that, the new class should be created. In my case the class name is `MyLanguageSyntaxErrorMessageProvider.java`. This class should then be filled with logic. For example, to overwrite the message I mentioned in my first post, the `getSyntaxErrorMessage()` in `MyLanguageSyntaxErrorMessageProvider` could look like this:

```
@Override
public SyntaxErrorMessage getSyntaxErrorMessage(IParserErrorContext context) {
    if (context.getRecognitionException() instanceof MismatchedTokenException) {
        MismatchedTokenException exception = (MismatchedTokenException) context.getRecognitionException();
        String value = exception.token.getText();
        return new SyntaxErrorMessage("The type of " + value + " is wrong.", IssueCodes.FALSE_PARAMETER_TYPE);
    }
    // additional implementations
    return null;
}
```

My class `IssueCodes.java` looks like the following (and can be extended with additional issue codes):

```
public interface IssueCodes {
    String PREFIX = "my.language.";

    String UNCAPITALIZED_ENTITY_NAME = "UncapitalizedEntityName";
    String FALSE_PARAMETER_TYPE = "FalseParameterType";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To override the message that the parser produced, you need to specialize the `org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.ISyntaxErrorMessageProvider` and bind your own implementation in the runtime module of your language.